# Spaces in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, spaces

I've just started learning Python 3 - and programming in general - and can't figure out how to put a space between Hello and a variable.

```
name = Amy 
print ('Hello' + name + '!' *3)
```

That prints out as **HelloAmy!!!**
How do you put a space between Hello and Amy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its as simple as adding a space withing the quotes. The interpreter prints what is directly given in the quotes.

```
print ('Hello ' + name + '!' *3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ('Hello ' + name + '!' *3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space in the existing string:

```
name = 'Amy'
print ('Hello ' + name + ('!' * 3))
#            ^ Space
```

or if `'Hello'` was defined by another variable, you could have just added another string containing only a space:

```
print (hello_string + ' ' + name + ('!' * 3))
```

I assuming `Amy` should have been in quotes